# R tryCatch with testthat expectation

Tags: r, testthat

I have the following function:

```
fun = function(expr) {
  mc = match.call()

  env = as.environment(within(
    list(),
    expr = eval(mc$expr)
  ))

  return(env)
}
```

that gets called within a `tryCatch()` so that any error conditions in `expr` are handled gracefully.

It works fine with a standard error condition:

```
tryCatch({
  fun({
    stop('error')
  })
}, error = function(e) {
  message('error happened')
})

# error happened
```

However, it does not capture `testthat` expectation errors (which is preferred for my specific use case):

```
library(testthat)

tryCatch({
  fun({
    expect_true(FALSE)
  })
}, error = function(e) {
  message('expectation not met')
})

# Error: FALSE isn't true.
```

or more simply:

```
library(testthat)

tryCatch({
  expect_true(FALSE)
}, error = function(e) {
  message('expectation not met')
})

# Error: FALSE isn't true.
```

The expectation error is not caught.

This issue appeared after upgrading from R 3.2.2 to R 3.3.0 - i.e. expectation errors were caught just fin in R 3.2.2.

Is there a way to make `testthat` expectations caught by `tryCatch()` in R 3.3.0?

Comment: The `expect_xxx` functions call `expect` which in turn calls `withRestarts`.  I don't know exactly what that does but it seems to be the root of the issue you're having.

Comment: @Dason Yes, I did notice that.  I'm not sure if that was always the case (e.g. back when first developed my code with R 3.2.2).  Ideally, I'd prefer to circumvent its current behavior without monkey patching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I set the debugger on `expect()` then stepped through a couple of lines of code (output edited for brevity), and looked at the class of the condition being signaled

```
> debug(expect)
> xx = expect_true(FALSE)
...
Browse[2]> n
debug: exp <- as.expectation(exp, ..., srcref = srcref)
Browse[2]>
...
Browse[2]> class(exp)
[1] "expectation_failure" "expectation"         "condition"   
Browse[2]> Q
> undebug(expect)
```

so it is not a condition of class 'error', and can be caught explicitly

```
> tryCatch(expect_true(FALSE), expectation_failure=conditionMessage)
[1] "FALSE isn't true.\n"
```

You could also catch the `expectation` class.

The restart allows you to continue, if that were somehow important.

```
result <- withCallingHandlers({
    expect_true(FALSE)
    expect_true(!TRUE)
    expect_true("this sentence")
}, expectation_failure=function(e) {
    cat(conditionMessage(e))
    invokeRestart("continue_test")
})
```

with output

```
FALSE isn't true.
!TRUE isn't true.
"this sentence" isn't true.
> result
[1] FALSE
```

One could also catch or handle successes

```
> tryCatch(expect_true(TRUE), expectation_success=class)
[1] "expectation_success" "expectation"         "condition"
```

Comment: Thanks! It certainly wasn't clear to me from the `tryCatch()` documentation that you could specify handlers for specific classes. Another one to add to my list of R tricks.